# Mutation function doesn't affect state variable

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In one of my store modules (`modal.js`) I have a dialog state variable and a `setDialogState` mutation that assigns a value to `dialog`.

When calling `setDialogState` from my component, `dialog` value doesn't change. I know it because the value of `this.$store.state.modal.dialog` hasn't changed and also Vue Devtools extension shows the same old value for `dialog`.

What's going on?

In my store module `store/modules/modal.js`:

```
const state = {
  dialog: false
}

const mutations = {
  setDialogState (state, payload) {
    this.state.dialog = payload;
    console.log(this.state.dialog); // strangely, this correctly logs the new value
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations
}
```

And in my component:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      dialog: state => state.modal.dialog
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.modal.dialog);
    this.$store.commit('modal/setDialogState', true);
    setTimeout(()=> {
      console.log(this.$store.state.modal.dialog);
    }, 2000); // this should log the new value, yet it still logs the old value
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `this` inside of mutation function on the store module.

Comment: Argh, that was it. Thanks so much, you can make an answer and I'll accept it if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access to `state` by reference of `this`, there u can't apply mutation of your state. 
The [mutation mechanism](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) is made to get the `state` in every function, then just have to use it as local variable inside of the current function.